# Kartik depdrop 404 errorUbuntu

Tags: yii2, apache2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I'm trying to use Kartik's depdrop but I keep getting a 404 file not found error on first menu pick
The line in the _form is

```
'onchange'=>'$.post("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('finaltest/listsubcat?id=').'"+$(this).val(),function(data){$("select#id").html(data);});
']);
```

which in the console says the post is sending to 
http://paie.loc/index.php?r=finaltest%2Flistsubcat%3Fid%3D10 with a 404 error
If I change the address in the navigator to 
http://paie.loc/index.php?r=finaltest%2Flistsubcat&id=10 I get the desired output for the 10th choice
The controller

```
  public function actionListsubcat($id)
    {
        $countsubcat =  Subcat::find()->where(['gfID' => $id])->count();
        $subcat =  Subcat::find()->where(['gfID' => $id])->orderBy('id')->all();
        if ($countsubcat > 0) {
            foreach ($subcat as $result) echo "<option value='".$result->id."'>".$result->name."</option>";
                  } else {
            echo "<option>-</option> ";
        }
    }
```

Ubuntu Mint 19
Apache2 server

I'm guessing it's something in apache2 but I've failed to find what
My paie.loc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
        ServerName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/paie.loc
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/payroll/frontend/web/"

        <Directory "/var/www/html/payroll/frontend/web/">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
         RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `createUrl()` in a wrong way - first parameter should be a route, so including `?id=` is incorrect. If you want to build URL with param, you should use array. You may need to try something like this:

```
'onchange' => '$.post("' 
    . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['finaltest/listsubcat', 'id' => '']) 
    . '" + $(this).val(), function(data){$("select#id").html(data);});
```

Comment: Did not work. I am currently doing a composer update of the system but I really think that my problem is not the PHP but is Apache2. The console says that the PHP is sending the data but that it is not going through. Hmmm just noticed that in the createUrl there is a ? which creates %3F in the url but & %26 is what works in the url when manually inputted. Will try when Composer finishes.

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong. `createUrl()` should not encode `?` and `&` in this case, you may be you're encoding this URL again.

Comment: From https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2

Comment: 'onchange'=>'
    $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('post/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
      $( "select#title" ).html( data );
    });

Comment: That wiki is incorrect. Did you at least read my answer? I proposed alternative way of generating this URL.

Comment: I did and it failed to transmit the selection.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in central Africa and not always online. Yes, I did try your code but according to the console the selection wasn't passed on. I'restarting from a clean install and will let you know what happens. Could you recommend a tutorial for three tiered dependent dropdowns?